# consuming grpc service using go

Tags: go, grpc, proto

I plan to use grpc as an inter-service sync communication protocol.
There are lots of different services and I have generated a `pb.go` file with all the relevant code for client and server using `protoc` with the go-rpc plugin.

Now I'm trying to figure out the best way or the common way of consuming this service from another service.
Here is what I have so far:

**Option 1**

1. use the `.proto` file from the service (download it)
2. run the `protoc` compiler and generate the `...pb.go` file for the consumer to use

**Option 2**

1. because the `...pb.go` is already generated on the grpc service side
   to implement the server and my client is another service written in
   go I can expose this as a sub module (another `.mod` file in a sub-
   directory)
2. use `go get github.com/usr/my-cool-grpc-service/client`

Option 2 seems more appealing to me because it makes the consumption of a service very easy and available for all other services that may require it.

On the other hand I know that the `.proto` file is the contract that cann generate clients for many different languages and should be used the the source of truth.

I fear that by choosing option 2 I'm unaware of any possible pitfalls I might encounter with regards to backwards compatibility or any other topic..

So, what is the idiomatic way of consuming a gRPC service?